# Time stamp comparison is wrong obj-c

Tags: objective-c, timestamp, boolean

I am comparing two dates below, with the result in binary (1 true 0 false) shown afterwards.

2017-01-31 07:03:19 +0000 < 2017-01-31 07:04:33 +0000, 0

Why is this comparison failing?

I am using obj-c and im using the CLLocation timestamps

Comment: paste some code. how are you comparing? NSCalendar compare?

Comment: Joshua, i do expain what i'm comparing and how i'm comparing, just read a little bit. I'm using Obj-c and CLLocation timestamps, with a simple operator in the middle of the two date. 

But maybe you are right that is unclear none the less i think you didn't read my question and you were just looking for code examples, it is funny how the guy below was able to figure out exactly what i wwanted, possibly because he read

Comment: there are many ways of how to achieve what you wanted. you have compare, you have nscalendar, and so on. now, if you did provide a sample code then maybe we could have start from there. your question is unclear of what you are currently using, stackoverflow is not a site that you post and we answer, its a site that enhances what you currently have. you just dont know how to use stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert these 2 string 2017-01-31 07:03:19 +0000 and 2017-01-31 07:04:33 +0000 into **NSDate**

Then you can compare both dates and get result.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:@"2017-01-31 07:03:19 +0000"];
NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:@"2017-01-31 07:04:33 +0000"];
if ([date1 compare:date2]==NSOrderedAscending) {
    NSLog(@"Date 2 is higher than Date 1");
}
else if ([date1 compare:date2]==NSOrderedDescending) {
    NSLog(@"Date 1 is higher than Date 2");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"Date 1 and Date 2 both are same");
}
```

Comment: They were actually Dates to start off as, but the comparing of dates part is what works, i was just comparing dates incorrectly